# Autotools configure build option not recognized

Tags: linux, build, cross-compiling, autotools, configure

I ran up into this glitch today, I am cross compiling many libraries for my linux system, and all except this zlib-1.2.8 works well.

My configure command is:

```
CFLAGS=-I/home/user/openwrt/openwrt/staging_dir/target-powerpc_8540_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include/ 
LDFLAGS=-L/home/user/openwrt/openwrt/staging_dir/target-powerpc_8540_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib/ 
./configure --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --host=powerpc-openwrt-linux-uclibcspe  
--prefix=/home/user/openwrt/openwrt/staging_dir/target-powerpc_8540_uClibc-0.9.33.2
```

The `--build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu` worked for all libraries, except this one.

THe error:

```
unknown option: --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
./configuer aborting
```

What is wrong? Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the configure script is not the usual one, but written especially for zlib, so the usual assumptions don't apply.

What you need for the --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu is --arches="-arch x86_64"

I don't think that you can cross-compile with the resulting Makefile without some tweaks (to CFLAGS probably).